# How to get current running job infos in program when I am using spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark SQL to run many `sqls`. My goal is to program to get information about their status, whether they are running or finished or failed, and which one of the `sqls` is Spark current processing.

I tried Spark listener but it work not so well, I cannont get current running sql using onJobStart or onJobEnd,  is there another way?
Below is code that similar to my usage of Spark SQL.

```
sqls = List(sql1, sql2, sql3,..,sqln)
```

In my Spark program:

```
sqls foreach {
  sql =>
     sparkSession.sql(sql)
}
```

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the SparkListeners did not work?  Can you post the code with SparkListeners for our understanding?

Comment: Mayby I used it in the wrong way, show me how it work